# What time will Ubuntu 16.04 LTS be available for upgrade in Ireland from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, updates, 16.04

I know that it is sometime today, I have updated all my software and it says up-to-date now. If I run update-manager -d in the therminal it does say that 16.04 LTS is available but in the release notes it says that it is a development update for testing. I was looking for the final release

Answer (score 2):

It's probably just a matter of time....if you can't wait try this:

In Software & Updates choose Download from: "Main server"

[image]

Then open the terminal and run

```
sudo apt update    
sudo update-manager -d
```

**EDIT:** also check this tab (in Software & Update)

[image]

Comment: No its still giving me the development release